# Not able to access files from old VDI in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I had a VM (VM1) in VirtualBox that no longer would boot due to a "GURU Meditation" error. So...

1. I created a new VM with a fresh install of Windows 10 (VM2), copied all the files associated with VM1 into the VM2 directory and mounted the VDI of VM1 in the Storage GUI of VirtualBox.
2. Booted up VM2 and can see the VDI of VM1 which shows (in Explorer) that the "drive" contains 356GB of data (all my old files).
3. I took ownership of the "drive" and added permissions to ensure "full control" of the VM1 VDI within VM2. I also set Explorer to view hidden folders.
4. When I open the VDI from VM1 it only shows a few folders: MSOCache, $Windows~BT, HP Driver, and a few others. None of my user files are visible! So, Explorer tells me they are there from the "data used" information, but I can't view or access them.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of `diskmgmt.msc`, it sounds like you have one partition mounted (the wrong partition).

Comment: Guru meditation? Les me guess, an Amiga 'disk' and amiga's fast file system. Which windows does not understand by default...

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I was not able to solve the GURU meditation issue. I was able to solve accessing my old files. I found them in a folder called "Found000". It was not visible in Explorer. I had to actually search for files with certain extensions. When they were found, I opened the "File Location" and found the user directory of the old machine.